# More efficient shared with me Query

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using the query: not 'me' in owners

to get a list of files shared with me.  But the query takes forever and often fails because of this.  I would like to just list stuff in the root folder also.  Is there a better way to this so I get a list like https://drive.google.com/#shared-with-me?

Comment: The query: not 'me' in owners and ('me' in writers or 'me' in readers) seems to be closer but still has to page over several requests and is very slow.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the new `sharedWithMe` field to list files that have been shared with the authorized user:

https://developers.google.com/drive/release-notes#sharedwithme_search_field_added